# How to post a hidden form value to a PHP page

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action="question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="12" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
header('Location: question.php');
?>
```

question.php File...

```
<?php

$rr = $_POST['session'];

echo $rr;

?>
```

it should print 12 right?

But i get this error "Notice: Undefined index: session in C:\wamp\www\Project\question.php on line 3".

what is the problem here?

thanks...

Comment: Take the `header()` command out and add a submit button to your form.

Comment: Redirect with header location doesn't mean that it automatically submits your form on the page. Also you shouldnt place header() after html part of your site, as you will get "headers already sent" error.

Comment: ok i got it now. the form doesn't get submitted. but what if i want to submit the from automatically without a submit button?

Comment: @user3520573 use javascript to auto submit your form on page load. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will `echo` your value once you click the submit button.

question.php File

```
<?php  
$rr = $_POST['session'];
echo $rr;
?>
```

HTML current page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="12" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

// this will auto submit your form using javaScript
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Can i do it without a submit button? like after the page is hit it redirects to "question.php" with post value of 12 and "question.php" echos 12?

Comment: I've added javascript that will autosubmit on page load

Comment: Just remove submit button. If you submit with JS, then you don't need that button anyway.

Comment: @user3520573 You could do the autosubmit/redirect with `php` using `curl` but that is a little more involved.

Answer (score 1):

But what if i want to submit the from automatically without a submit button:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pGg6/)

```
<form action="question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="12" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#sub').click();
});
```

Comment: use `$('#sub').closest('form').submit();` and you can get rid of that submit button at all.

Answer (score 0):

wow, pretty complicated... all you needed to do was add

```
<?php
session_start();
// session_start has to be the first line 
// of your php and before any HTML code
?>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action="question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="session" value="12" />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

question.php:

```
<?php
# prints all post elements
print_r($_POST); // for method="post"

echo $_POST['session']; # only the hidden input named "session"
```